# Attaching a hair particle system to a character rig

Tags: rigging, particles, hair

I've made a groom for my character and also a rig, and I'm trying to attach the groom so it follows the rig.

I put the armature modifier on top, and I also followed some instructions online to enable "Use modifier stack" in the particle settings, but once I enable it the hair just dissappears, and won't come back if I uncheck "use modifier stack".

It's my first time rigging and grooming in Blender and I just can't see where the problem is. I searched online and found nothing to help me, so i'm basically stuck. I could convert the particles to mesh, but that would be heavy on my scene, because my character is an animal with fur, so it's a lot of particles.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozcjsqquab9ywq3/Tarsier1.blend?dl=0

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.